# What does “there was no emotional resolve” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The album was finished with. ‘About You’ was Track 11 and there was a
> Track 10 called ‘This Feeling’. But because of what the song was
> about, and also sonic reasons, I was like, ‘That song can’t be on the
> album.’ But we had to deliver it in four days. So, I said if I could
> get to New York tomorrow, and Jack [Antonoff] was around, with a drum
> kit and a bass, I had a half-finished acoustic song that would be
> better for the record. It needed to finish, and at that moment, it
> didn’t—**there was no emotional resolve**. So, I went out there, a bit
> heartbroken post-breakup, and this was written, recorded and mixed in
> 30 hours.

This is a musician talking about how he made his new song. I’d like to know what “**there was no emotional resolve**” means. Does it mean that the song didn’t sound enough to make someone feel emotional?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do  you know what does it mean in this case?

Comment: "no emotional resolve" – not enough motivation *at that time*. But it was completed in the next 30 hours.

Comment: @WeatherVane Interesting. Seems the sentence is ambiguous. I think it's more likely what Michael Harvey was talking about in his deleted comments though, that it means "resolution" in the musical sense.

Comment: @gotube I supposed that from the quote's *"a bit heartbroken post-breakup"* which I thought affected the emotional ability to complete, rather than the musical ability.

Comment: I interpret it completely differently from Weather Vane, and more like gotube.    As a musician, I interpret it to mean that the song did not have an emotional *resolution*, because he says it was "half-finished", and "it needed to finish".

Comment: Thanks everyone for the interpretations. I googled emotional resolution, but I’m not sure I really get it. Is he basically saying that he thought that he should make the song more emotionally not conflicted?

Comment: Several of us seem to think that is means that the half-completed song did not come to a proper end and left the listener hanging so he had to write a finishing section to resolve the conflict of emotions. Does that help?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.  But thanks so much for the interpretation! I get it.